# Should Ecommerce sites use an obfuscated Order Id

Tags: database-design, e-commerce, security

I notice it is not standard practice to have a simple integer number for online shops when supplying the user an Order ID. Is this a security driven practice, or is it done to allow more orders with shorter character lengths?

If its a security driven practice, what is the best way to go about generating such an ID (considering the database likely uses an integer IDENTITY for the Order Table Primary Key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mainly so users can't view someone elses order.

If a user is assigned a shopping cart/order ID of 1000, it's safe to assume there was a 999 before and possibly a 1001 after.

There are ways to secure this, like ensuring the user is logged in and the order belongs to them. You can keep an integer identity for your primary key if it'd be easier for you to work with internally.

For the public facing side though, an easy way to obfuscate an Order ID is to assign a GUID to the record. Then instead of accessing a users order from the primary key, you'd access it through the GUID.

Comment: So as long as its secure (plugging in a different number doesn't give you access to that order) it isn't necessary to obfuscate it?

Comment: @Tyrsius, aside from not wanting users to know just how many orders someone processes (as Dommer has pointed out), I wouldn't see any need to obfuscate it if the orders are sufficiently secured.

Comment: Yeah I think if you do as Brandon said and make sure that only the shop admin or the relevant customer can see the order for a particular customer, you can use sequential numbers quite safely.

Comment: @Brandon Would it be a good idea to user Order ID as UUID type and using the same as user-facing ID?

Comment: @Sunny, for the most part that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use an integer as the identity but have an order ref field (which could still be indexed in the database) which is as you describe. I don't think it's a security issue, I think it might be a bit like the reason my first invoice I ever issued was NOT number `0001`. People generally don't want to advertise the fact that they have only just started out.

Having said all that, I can give you a snippet of code to generate a seemingly random alphanumeric order code of arbitrary length if you like.

Here is the code in C#: **EDIT: I have added the first (previously missing) line of code!**

```
    static System.Random random = new Random();
    int lengthOfOrderCode = 6; // Obviously put what you like here
    char[] keys = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890".ToCharArray(); // and here. Doesn't need to be the entire alphabet and numbers...
    var orderCode = GenerateOrderCode(keys, lengthOfOrderCode); 

    private static string GenerateOrderCode(char[] keys, int lengthOfOrderCode)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, lengthOfOrderCode).Select(k => keys[random.Next(0, keys.Length - 1)]).Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + b);
    }
```

Comment: That would be interesting, even if I don't use it. Please do!